# Updating multiple lines of a text file python

Tags: python

is there any way to update  multiple lines of a textfile using python.I want to delete the data between two lines My text file is as follows

```
Project
Post
<cmd> ---Some statements--
  ---Some statements---
Mycommand "Sourcepath" "DestPath"
</cmd>
Post
Lib
TargetMachine=MachineX86
Lib
Project
Post
<cmd> ---Some statements---
  ---Some statements---
Mycommand "Sourcepath" "DestPath"
</cmd>
Post
Lib
TargetMachine=MachineX64
Lib
```

I want to delete everything between cmd tag.So that the resulting text file should be as follows

```
Project
Post
<cmd>
</cmd>
Post
Lib
TargetMachine=MachineX86
Lib
Project
Post
<cmd>
</cmd>
Post
Lib
TargetMachine=MachineX64
Lib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can read the entire file into memory at once, I'd suggest

```
import re
with open("input.txt") as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(re.sub(r"(?s)<cmd>.*?</cmd>", "<cmd>\n</cmd>", infile.read()))
```

To only match tags that have `xcopy` in them, you need to expand the regex a little:

```
import re
with open("input.txt") as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(re.sub(
        r"""(?sx)<cmd>      # Match <cmd>.
        (?:                 # Match...
         (?!</cmd>)         #  (unless we're at the closing tag)
         .                  #  any character
        )*                  # any number of times.
        \bxcopy\b           # Match "xcopy" as a whole word
        (?:(?!</cmd>).)*    # (Same as above)
        </cmd>              # Match </cmd>""", 
        "<cmd>\n</cmd>", infile.read())
```

Comment: thank you tim for your Quick response

what to do if i want to delete the data between cmd only if it contain 'xcopy' string

Comment: Note that this won't properly process nested <cmd> tags, but it doesn't look you need to so it should be fine.

Comment: Hi  Tim Pietzcker

one more doubt.For some case i have to match XCOPY.ie i have to do above process for both XCOPY and xcopy.I tried with re.IGNORECASE but it didn't worked

Comment: Use `(?isx)` instead of `(?sx)` at the start of the regex.

Comment: ohh great
you are really a regex guru.Thank you.If you don't mind please suggest some topics for  regex